# Flesch-Kincaid reading ease formula coefficients

Tags: syntax, grammar

About the Flesch-Kincaid reading ease formula:

F = 206.835 − (84.6 ∗ S) − (1.015 ∗ P)

I don't understand the meaning of the coefficient choices. Why those specific numbers? Are the studies behind the choice of those numbers documented somewhere?

PS: I read another similar question in here where the answer is they have no meaning, but I can't find a source.

Comment: Entering "Flesh" and "Kincaid" in the search slot on top of this page can find you the other question ...

Comment: I wrote in the question that I have read that one, but that answer is still not clear to me

Comment: This should probably be added as a comment to the answer there asking for clarification. As it is this question is a duplicate

Comment: I'll do it then

Comment: These are regression coefficients. They have no inherent meaning, and would have been determined through a procedure such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares.

Comment: I see, now I get it. Thanks